# reference interfacecontroller in swift, watchkit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

**How can I get the Instance (*reference*) to the `InterfaceController` in my `ExtensionDelegate`?**

In my normal `AppDelegate` I do it like this:

`let vc = window?.rootViewController as! ViewController?`

but in the `InterfaceController` I don't know how to do it. I only have the standard Interface controller with the class `Interfacecontroller`(*The one you have when you create a new project*).

> Or if that doesn't work:

**How can I call a `pushnotification` and add an `observer` like `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(...)` in the `ExtensionDelegate` and the `InterfaceController`?**

> EDIT: what i want to achieve is i want to set a variable from the 
>   ExtensionDelegate.swift in the InterfaceController.swift.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rootInterfaceController](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtension_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKExtension/rootInterfaceController) property on WKExtension:

```
WKExtension.sharedExtension().rootInterfaceController
```

Comment: @JeffKelly That doesn't work. In my Interfacecontroller, there is a variable  `var gbdx:String!` and i want to set this var from the extensiondelegate. So i wrote in the extensiondelegate:`let ic = WKExtension.sharedExtension().rootInterfaceController` and then `ic.gbdx = "Something" `

Comment: When are you calling this method? Is it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`? You may need to wait until after that method finishes for `rootInterfaceController` to be populated; that method is where you can programmatically replace the interface from the storyboard, for instance. Try `applicationDidBecomeActive` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the [`WKExtension` instance's `rootInterfaceController` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtension_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKExtension/rootInterfaceController):

```
if let controller = WKExtension.sharedExtension().rootInterfaceController {
    // do something with controller
}
```

If you subclassed the interface controller, you'll need to explicitly cast it:

```
if let controller = WKExtension.sharedExtension().rootInterfaceController as? MyInterfaceControllerSubclass {
    // do something with controller
}
```

Comment: @BloodWoork See my update. You have to cast the interface controller so the compiler knows its correct type. Otherwise it will not see `gbdx`. Without the cast, the compiler only knows it's a plain old `WKInterfaceController`.

Comment: it gives me this impossible error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. All i did was: `let ic = WKExtension.sharedExtension().rootInterfaceController as? InterfaceController
    ic!.gbdx = "test"
    ic!.setgbd(ic!.gbdx)   
    `  But my function in the IC is : `
    func setgbd(name: String)
    {
        if gbdx != nil {
            print(gbdx)
        }
        
    }
`

Comment: my ExtensionDelegate: http://pastebin.com/eBDHF5jU and my InterfaceController: http://pastebin.com/5HSyL5iK

Comment: I think i found the problem: `WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class '_TtC28KardioApp_WatchKit_Extension19InterfaceController' to instantiate` I am adressing the wrong InterfaceController. The Controller i reference with your method doesn't exist...

Comment: Don't use `let`; use `if let` like in my example. Why do you have  `gbdx` as an implicitly unwrapped optional instead of a regular optional?

Comment: Ok so i created a new project and  i did what you said it just avoids a crash but i doesn't work. The  variable is still nil. So here is the IC: http://pastebin.com/QWWPv3k8 and the ED: http://pastebin.com/37zjAX4Z. PS: I didn't touch the Storyboard.